# Updating authentication cookie after less than half of the timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies

I want my `Authentication cookie` to renew even if less than half of the timeout has elapsed.

I am using `ASP.NET Identity` and OWIN.

In my Startup page I have this code:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
 {
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
      {
          AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
          LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
          SlidingExpiration = true,
          ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
      });
 }
```

This is the code in the `Login Page`:

```
 var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
 var signInManager = new SignInManager<AppUser, string>(userManager, authenticationManager);
 SignInStatus signInStatus = signInManager.PasswordSignIn(userName, password, isPersistent: true, shouldLockout: true);
```

Microsoft documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910443/understanding-the-forms-authentication-ticket-and-cookie) states

> If the Web page is accessed before half of the expiration time passes, the ticket expiration time will not be reset... the cookie is updated when more than half the specified time has elapsed.

Is there nonetheless some way to update an `authentication cookie` upon activity taking place even if less than half of the expiration time has elapsed?

Comment: which Identity version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Identity 2.0.

Comment: in identity 3 you can use RefreshSignInAsync() method of SignInManager, in identity 2 you can  use AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user); to refresh if less than half of the expiration time has elapsed